# Discrepancy in Lagrangian to Hamiltonian transformation results?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, operators, hamiltonian-formalism

I know,
$$ L=T-V       \;\;\; \; \;\;\;     [1]\;\;\; \; \;\;\; ( Lagrangian) $$ 
$$ H=T+V                            \;\;\; \; \;\;\;[2] \;\;\; \; \;\;\; (Hamiltonian)$$
   and logically, this leads to the equation,
$$ H - L= 2V               \;\;\; \; \;\;\;                                  [3a]$$
$$ H + L= 2T              \;\;\; \; \;\;\;                                  [3b]$$
but for given

$$\widehat{T}   $$
and
$$\widehat{V}$$
 equation [3] doesn't seem to hold. And we need an altogether different equation which is :
$$ H=\dot{q}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q} }-L\             \;\;\; \; \;\;\;                                   [4]$$

**1. Why is this happening?**

**2. Even if equation [4] does hold, the results obtained by equation  [3] &  [4] must coincide, which is certainly not the case?????**

An example in favour of my question :

$$\ H=\frac{p_{\theta}^{2}}{2 ml^{2 }}+mgl\left(1-\cos\theta\right)\ $$and was asked to find $$ \frac{\text{d}L}{\text{d}t}\ $$ Here the T and V terms are clearly visible but equation [3a] doesn't seem to work !

Comment: Is this question about classical or quantum mechanics?

Comment: It is about Classical mechanics. The given Hamiltonian belongs to a simple pendulum.

Comment: Then why are you replacing classical variables with linear operators? It seems like your confusion comes from using QM to learn classical mechanics

Comment: Are you saying that the first term is not T and the second not V but are intertwined?

Comment: @Aaron Stevens , I may be wrong, but I did it because the first term looked like \p^2 /2m\ and the second \mgx\ to me and that is why I tried to use equation [3a]!

Comment: I'm talking about equations 4 and 7

Comment: @Aaron Stevens , Sorry! I thought you were talking about the example Hamiltonian at the bottom. Anyways,I didn't tried to use Quantum Mechanics to solve the problem at the bottom , I just used equation [3a] to get to the answer but didn't succeed, and I had to use equation [6] .Equations [4] and [7] are just written to generalize the questions 1 and 2 (given in bold ) even to Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens , I am editing the question to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what you mean. In your example
$$H=\frac{p_{\theta}^2}{2ml^2}+mgl(1-\cos\theta)$$

We have:
$$T=\frac{p_{\theta}^2}{2ml^2}$$
$$V=mgl(1-\cos\theta)$$

So then we have $H=T+V$, and so we can easily write out equations $1$ and $2$ and then get to equation $3$.

I'm also unsure how $\frac{\text d L}{\text d t}$ relates to any of your previous discussion.

Comment: I also got the same answer but I am saying that equation [4] does not lead to the same result. And dL/dt was asked in the problem i. e. H was given and dL/dt was asked.

Comment: Equation 4 does lead to the same thing, you're probably making a mistake.